# Initialize array inside variadic template class

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, initialization-list

I cannot make my head around variadic tempates. I want to do very simple thing

```
Tuple t{1,2,3};
```

should crate tuple of size 3 containing array {1,2,3} ( `t.data = {1,2,3}`)

That means it should do 2 things:

- Create `Tuple<T,3>` size 3 ( `Tuple<>::data[3]` )
- fill `Tuple<>::data` with the numbers form std::initializer_list

This does not work:

```
template<typename T, T...args>
struct Tuple{
    T data[sizeof...(args)];
    Tuple(const T& args...):data{args...}{};
};
```

I tried all sorts of variations like:

```
template<typename T, T...args>
//template<typename T, Args...args>
struct Tuple{
    T data[sizeof...(args)];
    //T data{args...};

    //template <typename ...Args>
    //Tuple(T... args):data{args...}{};
    Tuple(const T& args...):data{args...}{};
    //Tuple(T* ...args):data{args...}{};
};
```

perhaps I don't get difference between 
`T...args` and `typename ...Args` and `args...`

I'm trying to use this as simple example to understand variadic templates and avoid using `std::initializer_list`

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot make my head around variadic tempates. I want to do very simple thing
>
> ```
> Tuple t{1,2,3};
> ```
>
> should crate tuple of size 3 containing `array {1,2,3}` ( `t.data = {1,2,3}`)

Not sure but, if I understand correctly, your trying to re-create `std::array`.

What you want it's impossible before C++17 because your `Tuple` it's a template class, so before C++17 you needs to explicit the template arguments.

Starting from C++17, you can use deduction guides.

What you want (again: if I understand correctly) is almost the [`std::array` deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides)

> ```
> template <class T, class... U>
> array(T, U...) -> array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
> ```

In you case become

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Tuple
 {
   T data[N];
 };

template <typename T, typename ... U>
Tuple(T, U...) -> Tuple<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;    

int main ()
 {
   Tuple t{1, 2, 3};

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(t), Tuple<int, 3u>> );
 }
```

Observe that a constructor isn't strictly required because the argument are used to initialize the member (the C-style array).

This deduction guide

```
template <typename T, typename ... U>
Tuple(T, U...) -> Tuple<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

deduce the type of the `Tuple::data` array from the first argument and the other argument are used only to deduce the size of the array; this can be a problem if the types of the arguments are different; by example

```
Tuple t1{1l, 2, 3};  // become Tuple<long, 3u>
Tuple t2{2, 2l, 3};  // become Tuple<int, 3u>
```

Take also in count that, for `std::array`

> The program is ill-formed if `(std::is_same_v<T, U> && ...)` is not `true`

To solve this problem and have something more flexible, you can use `std::common_type_t`, as suggested in other answers, so deduction guide become

```
template <typename ... Ts>
Tuple(Ts...) -> Tuple<std::common_type_t<Ts...>, sizeof...(Ts)>;
```

and both cases become `Tuple<long, 3u>`

```
Tuple t1{1l, 2, 3};  // become again Tuple<long, 3u>
Tuple t2{2, 2l, 3};  // now become Tuple<long, 3u>
```

---

> Perhaps I don't get difference between T...args and typename ...Args and args...

Look for a good C++ book but, making it simple

(1)  `typename ... Args` declare a template variadic sequence of **types**, for a class/struct, for a `using` declaration, for a deduction guide, for a function.

So

```
 template <typename ... Args>
 struct foo
  { };
```

define a template struct that receive zero or more template **types** arguments and you can declare a variable as follows

```
 foo<short, int, long, long long> f;
```

(2) `T ... args` declare a variadic template list not of types but of elements of type `T`

What is `T`? Another template parameter.

So, by example, one of your `Tuple` version in your question

template 
   struct Tuple
    { /* ... */ };

and a variable should be declared as follows

```
Tuple<int, 1, 2, 3>  t{1, 2, 3}
```

that is very redundant in your case.

(3) `args...` (with ellipsis after the name) is the **use** a variadic list (of types or values)

By example

```
template <typename ... Args>
void foo (Args ... args)
 { bar(args...); }
```

declare and define a variadic template `foo()` function with a template variadic list of types

```
 template <typename ... Args> // <--- declare a variadic list of types Args
```

and at every type correspond a value, so you declare also a variadic list `args` of values

```
 void foo (Args ... args) // <--- declare a variadic list of args values of types Args
```

and the statement expand the pack of values `args` and pass they to another function

```
 bar(args...);  // <--- expand the args pack and pass the value to bar.
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using `std::index_sequence`:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t> using always_t = T;

template <typename T, typename Seq> struct Tuple;

template <typename T, std::size_t...Is>
struct Tuple<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>{
    T data[sizeof...(Is)];

    Tuple(const always_t<T, Is>&... args) : data{args...}{}
};

// Deduction guide (C++17)
template <typename ... Ts>
Tuple(const Ts&...) -> Tuple<std::common_type_t<Ts...>, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>>;

Tuple a{1,2,3,4,5};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbd3626ba8f7c792)

Answer (score 0):

This is surprisingly difficult. The only way I could think of making this work is to have the array size as a template parameter, instead of somehow deducing this from the actual constructor parameters, and to use C++17 deduction guides.

Tested with gcc 9.1, with `-std=c++17`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, size_t n>
struct Tuple{
    T data[n];
    template<typename ...Args>
    Tuple(Args && ...args):data{std::forward<Args>(args)...}{};
};

template<typename ...Args>
Tuple(Args && ...args)
-> Tuple<std::common_type_t<std::remove_reference_t<Args>...>,
     sizeof...(args)>;


Tuple a{1,2,3,4,5};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(a),
                    Tuple<int, 5>> << std::endl;

    std::cout << a.data[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to get what `std::common_type_t<std::remove_reference_t<Args>...>` does. Can be this `template<typename ...Args>
Tuple(Args && ...args)
-> ` made more general to work for any similar template class constructor, not just `Tuple` ?

Comment: still does not work `expect constructor,destructor or type conversion before ;` ... so I tried to add it like `-> Tuple<std::common_type_t<std::remove_reference_t<Args>...>,sizeof...(args)>::Tuple(Args && ...args);
` but that `expects type specifier`

Comment: No, you have to use a deduction guide, in the manner I outlined, and a compiler that supports C++17. I do not believe that template parameters can be deduced directly from a constructor call, in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

based on [this good explanation](https://jgreitemann.github.io/2018/09/15/variadic-expansion-in-aggregate-initialization/).

#1 create an array of nth generated integers

```
template <typename Container, int... I>
Container iota_impl(std::integer_sequence<int, I...>) {
    return {I...};
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
auto iota_array() {
    using Sequence = std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>;
    return iota_impl<std::array<T, N>>(Sequence{});
}
...
auto arr1 = iota_array<int, 10>();
```

will create **std::array<int, 10>{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}**

#2 create an array of integer passed via initializer_list

```
template <typename T, T...I>
auto iota_array2() {
    constexpr auto N = sizeof...(I);
    return std::array<T, N>({I...});
}
...
auto arr2 = iota_array2<int, 3,2,7,4,5,6>();
```

will create **std::array<int, 6>{3,2,7,4,5,6}**

PS if it should be wrapped in Tuple, it can be.
PPS c++17